# How to combine two data sets (level-1 and level-2 data sets) for multilevel analysis in R

Tags: r, dataset, multilevel-analysis

I want to analyze data from TIMSS on mathematics. Data contains two data sets one for student level information (i.e. level-1) and another one for school level information (i.e. level-2). Data sets are provided in two different files and each file contains school ID variable.

As far as I know, I can't do multilevel analysis with these two data sets and these have to be combined into one data set.Am I right?

I tried to use `reshape` and `reshape2` for combining the two data set but it didn't work. In level-1 data I have SchoolID,motivation, confidence, learningApproach and math scores. Data looks like:

```
SchoolID studentID motivation confidence learningApproach math
100123  10012301    23  10  12        45
100123  10012302    32  5   16        67
100123  10012303    14  7   21        89
.                   
.                   
.                   
110223  11023301    13  7   18        77
110223  11023302    24  7   11        98
110223  11023303    16  8   12        56
```

In level-2 data I have SchoolID and resources. Data looks like:

```
SchoolID    resources
100123      45.5
100223      66.7
1106303     34
110223      22.3
```

Could you please guide me on how to combine these two data sets in an appropriate way for using with `lme4` package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `merge()`:

```
combined <- merge(x=level1data, y=level2data, by="SchoolID")
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for.Is there any reverse method?

Comment: @Amin what do you mean by reverse? do you mean getting back to your level-2 data? I think what I would do would be this: `level2data <- combined[duplicated(combined$SchoolID) == FALSE, c("SchoolID", "resources")]`. The bit `duplicated(combined$SchoolID) == FALSE` selects rows for the first occurrence of each SchoolID, then `c("SchoolID", "resources")` only keep the SchoolID and resources columns.